# Tough mysql nested table result challenge

Tags: mysql, nested

I'm messing with wordpress making an API for my plug-in that jquery uses to populate a table.  Need help with figuring out how I'm going to do this.

First query, this will get the 'parent' posts:

[q1]:
`Select * from posts as p where p.ID IN ({SomeIDs I am requesting})`

second query, this will get all the children of the first:

[q2]:
`Select * from posts as p where p.parent_postID IN ({the parentIDs from q1})`

How can I run this query so that the results are one output.  I don't want to have to keep running the second query every time I want to show the children (the children are shown as a default, the idea is so I can LIMIT on the first query).

End result:

```
_________________________________________________
| ID   | post_parent | title      | disruption  |
-------------------------------------------------
| 894  |           0 | main title | main disc   |
| 898  |         894 | diff title | diff disc   |
| 907  |         894 | diff tilte | diff disc   |
| 910  |           0 | Main title | main disc   |
| 916  |         910 | diff title | diff disc   |
| 919  |           0 | Main title | Main disc   | 
-------------------------------------------------
```

You will notice ID 919 has no children, I still want it to display in the results.

So I tried joining, I would lose the records that do not have ID = post_parentID unless there is another type of join I can do...

The idea is 'LIMIT' on q1 with combined results sorted with q2,  then the results for  jQuerys forloop when making the table will just change the bg of the `<TR>` if the ID and post_parent are a match

This is the scheme I have to work with... Wordpress's;  also not that there will be additional criteria in q2 as to which children I want to show.  Example.  I will be adding a post_meta to the children.... meta_key = 'lang_i18N' meta_value='en' so I may add a join to q2 for the postmeta

UPDATE:

This is q1:

[q1]

```
    SELECT
        posts.ID AS myItem_ID,
        posts.post_parent AS parentID,
        posts.post_title AS title,
        posts.post_content AS fullDesc,
        posts.post_excerpt AS shortDesc,
        posts.post_status AS status,
        posts.menu_order AS fetured_Order,
        json_meta.meta_value AS json_input,
        meta.meta_value AS vendorID,
        vendor.post_title AS vendorName,
        posts.post_modified AS modifiedDate
    FROM wp_posts AS posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta
        ON meta.post_id = posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS json_meta
        ON json_meta.post_id = posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS i18N
        ON i18N.post_id = posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS vendor
        ON vendor.ID = meta.meta_value
    WHERE meta.meta_key = 'agency'
    AND json_meta.meta_key = 'json_input'
    AND posts.post_type = 'activity_item'
    AND posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND posts.ID IN (1080, 1231, 1273, 1882, 1937)
    LIMIT 0,2
```

ok That gives me the Parent listings... Now I want to include the children with the same as q1 but maybe i want the `i18N = 'es'` meaning I want the parent that is whatever value field i18N has, but I want the children that are 'es' and maybe there are 4children, Well I want the LIMIT to show only 2 parents, and however many Children they have (not limiting the children) can this be done in one Query?  I'm trying to stay away from PHP only because it's a lot of data.

Comment: If i did a UNION could I still sort so that the children are together?

Comment: Why not simply use an `OR` clause and include the posts that don't have any parent ?

Comment: but i want to LIMIT on q1 not all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use recursive function in php to get all nested sub rows for a parent row then can use the below one:-

```
function get_categories_subcategories($id)
{
    $condition = isset($id)?"post_parent=".$id."":"post_parent=0";
    $sql="select id,post_parent,title,disruption from posts where ".$condition."";    

    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    $arr = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
    { 
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {   
         $arr[] = array(
         "id" => $result["id"],
         "post_parent" => $result["post_parent"],
         "title" => $result["title"],
         "disruption" => $result["disruption"],
         "child" => get_categories_subcategories($result["id"])
      );     
        }        
    }
    return $arr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select 
id,
if_null(post_parent_id,0)

from posts as p 

left join 

(Select parent_id from posts where id= ?/*input*/) as parent_temp_table

on (parent_temp_table.parent_id = p.postID)
```

Comment: this looks more like what I want, however... let me update the SQL so you see the whole picture.